# open and close on mouse click to change a part of a page

Tags: html, css

I am building a page with a portfolio in Dreamweaver CS4 with HTML and CSS. The page will have a 'box' which contains small images representing different pieces of work. When clicking on one of the small images, I want to load a new 'box' on top of the old box, which contains information about that piece. The new box should totally cover the old box and the new box needs to have a 'close' function which will then remove it and again reveal the original page. While the box changes, I'd like the rest of the page to stay exactly as it is. I want to have this function for each of the small images.

I am a beginner with limited knowledge so I'm looking for the easiest way to do this, and would really appreciate any advice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use javascript to set div hidden or visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery Captify Plugin](http://thirdroute.com/projects/captify/)

There are many ways to do this, all of them would involve javascript. Sample HTML:

```
<div class="smallimage">
    <img src="...." />
    <div class="explanation">Lorem ipsum blah</div> 
</div>
```

Having set .explanation to display: none, you can use some jquery code like this to display/hide it when the image is clicked (put it in your document.ready function)

```
$('.smallimage').click(function(){
    $('.explanation', this).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thank u @waitinforatrain. This isn't exactly what I'm trying to do but helps: so imagine if on this page http://thirdroute.com/projects/captify/ you could click on one of the four images to open a new screen (page with text and images) that loads on top to completely cover all the four images. This would have a close button to remove it and reveal the four images again. Each image would be clickable and each of the new screens would have different content but in a box of exactly the same size and positioning, covering the four images completely. Any ideas how I can achieve that? Many thanks.

Comment: It covers the four images but not the full screen right? Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/waitinforatrain/RbvTK/14/ , let me know if you have any question about how it works. Also, I have only tested it in Chrome

Comment: Many many thanks @waitinforatrain - that is exactly the effect I am looking for. As I can't get it to work other than in this jsfiddle I am wondering if I'm doing something very basic wrong - can I just check that with the javascript, do I just put this <script type="text/javascript">
$('.image').click(function() {
   id=$(this).attr('id');
   $("#"+id+"_box").show();
});

$('.close').click(function() {
   $(".imagebox").hide();   
});
</script> into the head part of the document? Is that correct or have I got the <script> tags wrong somehow? Thanks again!!

Comment: Yes but with javascript, the html elements won't exist until the page is finished loading and so the javascript won't work properly. Without jQuery you would use the <body> onLoad attribute. With jQuery all you have to is wrap all of the javascript code like this:  $(function() { //JAVASCRIPT CODE HERE }). This is jQuery's way of saying "do this when the page has finished loading)

Comment: Thank u again, @waitinforatrain, but I'm sorry, I still can't make it work. I included the link to the jQuery in the HTML, or so I thought, I am not even sure if I am doing it right. Here is my HTML code http://jsfiddle.net/HZZzF/ - would you be able to tell me if the part calling the jQuery / java script is even in the right place / written correctly? I tried to follow the instructions from this tutorial http://bit.ly/eLvtXK but I think I am not including it properly. Many thanks again.

Comment: There's two problems with the jsfiddle you provided. First is that it's missing the CSS from my fiddle. The seconds is that you forgot to put in "});" at the end of the javascript to close the round and curly brackets from "$(function() {". If you're using Chrome (or Firefox with the Firebug extension) you can find this out by right-clicking the page, clicking "Inspect Element", click the "Console" tab and it will show you the javascript errors and which line is causing the error. In this case the error was "unexpected end of input" meaning the javascript interpreter expected more code.

Answer (score 0):

Create one container (like a div) and let it have two children, one being the 'old box', containing the thumbnail, one being the 'new box' containing the info.  Style both of these children to occupy their parent completely.

Now just set the `display` to `none` on the 'new box' and use javascript to toggle which one is shown.  I suggest you look into jQuery for this.

So you'll have something like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="#" class="toggleLink">
      ...
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="info">
    <a href="#" class="toggleLink">
      ...
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('a.toggleLink').click(function(){
      var container = $(this).closest('div.container');
      $(container).find('div.thumbnail').toggle();
      $(container).find('div.info').toggle();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Disclaimer: *I didn't actually test this code, but it should be about right.  Use it as a concept, don't just copy-paste it.*

Comment: Hi @Joeri Hendrickx, many thanks 4 ur answer. Unfortunately I'm a newbie & don't understand what 2 do. I did what u suggest, created a div w/ 2 divs (same size) inside it & hid the 'info' div, I also included the script in the head. But when i click nothing happens. Am I supposed 2 put something in place of the #? What I'd like is many small images on the same page, each loading a new screen on top covering ALL of them, and then close it from within itself. Is this possible using what u suggest or will it only work for 1 element of the same size covering the parent? Sorry - I don't understand.

Comment: @noobug: this solution is only for switching between display/info of one thumbnail; but you could use more or less the same approach for the whole thing.  This code will only work if you include jQuery, so google that and start from there.  Try to understand how it works, don't just blindly copy-paste it.  Also, for opening up your image, I suggest you look into lightbox or one of its competitors.